# How do I prove growth of functions with exponents?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that $16 + 3^n=O(4^{n})$.
I have tried to do this problem but cannot find a constant $c$ that I am supposed to find.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that For $n\ge 3$, $3^n+16< 4^n$.
You can show it by induction if you want

Answer (score 1):

$$16+3^n\le17(4^n)\text{ for all } n\in\mathbb{R^+}$$
So we can use $c=17$ if we want the Big-O notation to be valid for all positive $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Argue that
$$
\frac{16+3^n}{4^n}\to 0
$$
as $n\to \infty$ and hence that $16+3^n<4^n$ for sufficiently large $n$ by the definition of the limit.